# Rails lograge log not coming as json, request id is appended as prefix

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging

After adding lograge, in my rails application logs are coming as JSON, but request id is also getting appended, how to get rid off this, attaching sample image of logs and lograge configs.

````
  config.lograge.enabled = true
  config.lograge.base_controller_class = ['ActionController::API']
  
  config.lograge.custom_options = lambda do |event|
    {
      request_time: Time.now,
      application: Rails.application.class.parent_name,
      process_id: Process.pid,
      host: event.payload[:host],
      remote_ip: event.payload[:remote_ip],
      ip: event.payload[:ip],
      x_forwarded_for: event.payload[:x_forwarded_for],
      params: event.payload[:params].to_json,
      exception: event.payload[:exception]&.first,
      request_id: event.payload[:headers]['action_dispatch.request_id'],
    }.compact
  end ```


Log output

```[edca3b13-f24b-41b9-885b-2f7a554ec061] {"user_id":"5da40f0274a0f370a1fa941b","current_group":"customer","ip":"127.0.0.1","host":"localhost","message":"Use a queueing backend to enqueue jobs in the future. Read more at https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html","back_trace":["/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/activejob-6.0.4.7/lib/active_job/queue_adapters/inline_adapter.rb:19:in `enqueue_at'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/activejob-6.0.4.7/lib/active_job/enqueuing.rb:57:in `block in enqueue'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/activesupport-6.0.4.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:112:in `block in run_callbacks'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/newrelic_rpm-8.0.0/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/active_job.rb:61:in `block in run_in_trace'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/newrelic_rpm-8.0.0/lib/new_relic/agent/method_tracer.rb:75:in `block in trace_execution_scoped'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/newrelic_rpm-8.0.0/lib/new_relic/agent/method_tracer_helpers.rb:30:in `block in trace_execution_scoped'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/newrelic_rpm-8.0.0/lib/new_relic/agent/tracer.rb:355:in `capture_segment_error'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/newrelic_rpm-8.0.0/lib/new_relic/agent/method_tracer_helpers.rb:30:in `trace_execution_scoped'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/newrelic_rpm-8.0.0/lib/new_relic/agent/method_tracer.rb:73:in `trace_execution_scoped'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/newrelic_rpm-8.0.0/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/active_job.rb:60:in `run_in_trace'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/newrelic_rpm-8.0.0/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/active_job.rb:38:in `enqueue'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/newrelic_rpm-8.0.0/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/active_job.rb:19:in `block (4 levels) in \u003ctop (required)\u003e'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/activesupport-6.0.4.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:121:in `instance_exec'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/activesupport-6.0.4.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:121:in `block in run_callbacks'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/activesupport-6.0.4.7/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:180:in `block in instrument'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/activesupport-6.0.4.7/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:24:in `instrument'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/activesupport-6.0.4.7/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:180:in `instrument'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/activejob-6.0.4.7/lib/active_job/logging.rb:32:in `block (2 levels) in \u003cmodule:Logging\u003e'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/activesupport-6.0.4.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:121:in `instance_exec'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/activesupport-6.0.4.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:121:in `block in run_callbacks'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/activejob-6.0.4.7/lib/active_job/logging.rb:16:in `block (3 levels) in \u003cmodule:Logging\u003e'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/activejob-6.0.4.7/lib/active_job/logging.rb:45:in `block in tag_logger'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/activesupport-6.0.4.7/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:80:in `block in tagged'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/activesupport-6.0.4.7/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:28:in `tagged'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/activesupport-6.0.4.7/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:80:in `tagged'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/activejob-6.0.4.7/lib/active_job/logging.rb:45:in `tag_logger'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/activejob-6.0.4.7/lib/active_job/logging.rb:15:in `block (2 levels) in \u003cmodule:Logging\u003e'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/activesupport-6.0.4.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:121:in `instance_exec'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/activesupport-6.0.4.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:121:in `block in run_callbacks'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/activesupport-6.0.4.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:139:in `run_callbacks'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/activejob-6.0.4.7/lib/active_job/enqueuing.rb:55:in `enqueue'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/shoryuken-5.2.3/lib/shoryuken/extensions/active_job_extensions.rb:31:in `enqueue'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/activejob-6.0.4.7/lib/active_job/configured_job.rb:16:in `perform_later'","/Users/giri.shankar/RubymineProjects/ca-loans-api/lib/publishable.rb:49:in `publish_action'","/Users/giri.shankar/RubymineProjects/ca-loans-api/lib/publishable.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in publishable'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/activesupport-6.0.4.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:428:in `instance_exec'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/activesupport-6.0.4.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:428:in `block in make_lambda'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/activesupport-6.0.4.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:238:in `block in halting_and_conditional'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/activesupport-6.0.4.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:517:in `block in invoke_after'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/activesupport-6.0.4.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:517:in `each'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/activesupport-6.0.4.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:517:in `invoke_after'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/activesupport-6.0.4.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:136:in `run_callbacks'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/mongoid-7.2.6/lib/mongoid/interceptable.rb:135:in `run_callbacks'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/mongoid-7.2.6/lib/mongoid/persistable/creatable.rb:121:in `block in prepare_insert'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/activesupport-6.0.4.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:135:in `run_callbacks'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/mongoid-7.2.6/lib/mongoid/interceptable.rb:135:in `run_callbacks'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/mongoid-7.2.6/lib/mongoid/persistable/creatable.rb:120:in `prepare_insert'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/mongoid-7.2.6/lib/mongoid/persistable/creatable.rb:25:in `insert'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/mongoid-7.2.6/lib/mongoid/persistable/savable.rb:25:in `save'","/Users/giri.shankar/RubymineProjects/ca-loans-api/app/controllers/api/v1/transactions_controller.rb:42:in `create'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/actionpack-6.0.4.7/lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:6:in `send_action'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/actionpack-6.0.4.7/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:195:in `process_action'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/actionpack-6.0.4.7/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:30:in `process_action'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/actionpack-6.0.4.7/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:42:in `block in process_action'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/activesupport-6.0.4.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:135:in `run_callbacks'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/actionpack-6.0.4.7/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:41:in `process_action'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/actionpack-6.0.4.7/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:22:in `process_action'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/actionpack-6.0.4.7/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:33:in `block in process_action'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/activesupport-6.0.4.7/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:180:in `block in instrument'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/activesupport-6.0.4.7/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:24:in `instrument'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/activesupport-6.0.4.7/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:180:in `instrument'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/actionpack-6.0.4.7/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `process_action'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/actionpack-6.0.4.7/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:245:in `process_action'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/mongoid-7.2.6/lib/mongoid/railties/controller_runtime.rb:22:in `process_action'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/actionpack-6.0.4.7/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/actionview-6.0.4.7/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:39:in `process'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/actionpack-6.0.4.7/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:190:in `dispatch'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/actionpack-6.0.4.7/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:254:in `dispatch'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/actionpack-6.0.4.7/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `dispatch'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/actionpack-6.0.4.7/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:33:in `serve'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/actionpack-6.0.4.7/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:18:in `block in \u003cclass:Constraints\u003e'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/actionpack-6.0.4.7/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:48:in `serve'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/actionpack-6.0.4.7/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:49:in `block in serve'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/actionpack-6.0.4.7/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:32:in `each'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/actionpack-6.0.4.7/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:32:in `serve'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/actionpack-6.0.4.7/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:834:in `call'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/newrelic_rpm-8.0.0/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:101:in `call'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/newrelic_rpm-8.0.0/lib/new_relic/rack/agent_hooks.rb:30:in `traced_call'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/newrelic_rpm-8.0.0/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:101:in `call'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/newrelic_rpm-8.0.0/lib/new_relic/rack/browser_monitoring.rb:33:in `traced_call'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/newrelic_rpm-8.0.0/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:101:in `call'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/rack-attack-6.5.0/lib/rack/attack.rb:99:in `call'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/newrelic_rpm-8.0.0/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:101:in `call'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/method_override.rb:24:in `call'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/newrelic_rpm-8.0.0/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:101:in `call'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/actionpack-6.0.4.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:654:in `call'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/newrelic_rpm-8.0.0/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:101:in `call'","/Users/giri.shankar/RubymineProjects/ca-loans-api/app/middleware/health_middleware.rb:11:in `call'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/newrelic_rpm-8.0.0/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:101:in `call'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:40:in `call'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/newrelic_rpm-8.0.0/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:101:in `call'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/newrelic_rpm-8.0.0/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:101:in `call'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/actionpack-6.0.4.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `block in call'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/activesupport-6.0.4.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:101:in `run_callbacks'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/actionpack-6.0.4.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `call'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/newrelic_rpm-8.0.0/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:101:in `call'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/actionpack-6.0.4.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/actionable_exceptions.rb:18:in `call'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/newrelic_rpm-8.0.0/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:101:in `call'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/actionpack-6.0.4.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:32:in `call'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/newrelic_rpm-8.0.0/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:101:in `call'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/actionpack-6.0.4.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `call'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/newrelic_rpm-8.0.0/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:101:in `call'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/lograge-0.12.0/lib/lograge/rails_ext/rack/logger.rb:18:in `call_app'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/railties-6.0.4.7/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/activesupport-6.0.4.7/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:80:in `block in tagged'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/activesupport-6.0.4.7/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:28:in `tagged'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/activesupport-6.0.4.7/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:80:in `tagged'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/railties-6.0.4.7/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/newrelic_rpm-8.0.0/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:101:in `call'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/actionpack-6.0.4.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/newrelic_rpm-8.0.0/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:101:in `call'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/request_store-1.5.1/lib/request_store/middleware.rb:19:in `call'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/newrelic_rpm-8.0.0/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:101:in `call'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/actionpack-6.0.4.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:27:in `call'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/newrelic_rpm-8.0.0/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:101:in `call'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/newrelic_rpm-8.0.0/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:101:in `call'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/activesupport-6.0.4.7/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/newrelic_rpm-8.0.0/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:101:in `call'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/actionpack-6.0.4.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/newrelic_rpm-8.0.0/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:101:in `call'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:110:in `call'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/newrelic_rpm-8.0.0/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:101:in `call'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/actionpack-6.0.4.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/host_authorization.rb:97:in `call'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/newrelic_rpm-8.0.0/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:101:in `call'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/rack-cors-1.0.6/lib/rack/cors.rb:98:in `call'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/newrelic_rpm-8.0.0/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:101:in `call'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/railties-6.0.4.7/lib/rails/engine.rb:527:in `call'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/newrelic_rpm-8.0.0/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:101:in `call'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/puma-5.5.2/lib/puma/configuration.rb:249:in `call'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/puma-5.5.2/lib/puma/request.rb:77:in `block in handle_request'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/puma-5.5.2/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:340:in `with_force_shutdown'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/puma-5.5.2/lib/puma/request.rb:76:in `handle_request'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/puma-5.5.2/lib/puma/server.rb:447:in `process_client'","/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@loans/gems/puma-5.5.2/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:147:in `block in spawn_thread'"]}
[edca3b13-f24b-41b9-885b-2f7a554ec061] {"method":"POST","path":"/term_loans","format":"json","controller":"Api::V1::TermLoans::TransactionsController","action":"create","status":500,"duration":2474.23,"view":0.24,"request_time":"2022-09-23 19:51:12 +0530","application":"MarketPlaceApi","process_id":50370,"params":"{\"term_loan_transaction\":{\"tenor\":{\"years\":4,\"months\":2,\"days\":23},\"interest\":{\"type\":\"fixed\",\"value\":\"30.01\"},\"facility_limit\":80000000,\"security_type\":\"unsecured\",\"customer_id\":\"5b63fb7481d7a674b608235a\",\"disbursement_date\":\"2021-09-16\"},\"format\":\"json\",\"controller\":\"api/v1/term_loans/transactions\",\"action\":\"create\",\"transaction\":{}}","request_id":"edca3b13-f24b-41b9-885b-2f7a554ec061"}
````

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is configurable through the use of different formatters. To output in JSON format for example:

```
config.lograge.formatter = Lograge::Formatters::Json.new
```

Perhaps you've already set a formatter, but double check it and it's setup to make sure it's what you want.

The Lograge gem readme file has a small section on the formatters available.  See [here](https://github.com/roidrage/lograge) at about the middle of the page.